# getting error WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'

Tags: testing, robotframework

here is my first and simple code in robot framework , I am just trying to input text in google searchbox and then close the browser but it keeps on failing.

```
*** Settings ***
     Documentation    Suite description
         Library  Selenium2Library


*** Variables ***
     ${Browser}  chrome
     ${URL}  https://www.google.com/
     ${text}  ab

*** Test Cases ***
    TC 001 Browser Open and Close
        Open Browser  ${URL}  ${Browser}
        Set Browser Implicit Wait    5
        Input Text  name=q   ab
        Close Browser
```

error message -

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
(Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
**strong text**
Strange thing if i run only below it works fine so i am suspecting it has to do with step where i am trying to insert text in google search box

```
*** Settings ***
    Documentation    Suite description
        Library  Selenium2Library


*** Variables ***
    ${Browser}  chrome
    ${URL}  https://www.google.com/
    ${text}  ab


*** Test Cases ***
      TC 001 Browser Open and Close
          Open Browser  ${URL}  ${Browser}
          Set Browser Implicit Wait    5
          Close Browser
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the correct chromedriver version for your version of chrome. The error shows you're using chrome 80, but chromedriver 2.33. You need to be using chromedriver version 80.